# I need a function to get desired column by matching other column values

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two tables.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2
[image]

Now I want a function to compare Test column and when they are equal (for example row 2 of table matches row 3 and 4 of table 2) I need to compare the price column to check the max (in this example row 3 600 is greater than row 4 550) and then return my chosen column. So this should return "pixel as Value1" and "4 as rank".

I tried VLOOKUP, IF but was not able to merge them to get the desired result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel-365 they could use `FILTER()` and `SORT()` function with `INDEX()`. Try-

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER($E$9:$G$12,$D$9:$D$12=$A2),3,-1),1,COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: awesome :) This worked for me

Comment: @Curious Glad to know! If this work then please mart it as answered (tick mark).

Answer (score 2):

Quite similar to @Harun's answer, but I used:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(E$2:H$5,E$2:E$5=A2),4,-1),{2,3}),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have Excel-365, you could do like this.

[image]

My formula in cell B3 is:

```
=INDEX($B$14:$B$17;MATCH(A3&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$14:$A$17=A3)*$D$14:$D$17));$A$14:$A$17&$D$14:$D$17;0))
```

Formula in cell C3 is almost the same, just change first argument on INDEX to retrieve Rank column:

```
=INDEX($C$14:$C$17;MATCH(A3&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$14:$A$17=A3)*$D$14:$D$17));$A$14:$A$17&$D$14:$D$17;0))
```

Notice both formulas are array formulas so they must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work!

Also, if the test is not found, it will raise an error. For example, now with values `a` and `d` won't work because those values are not present in Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option if you're not running Excel 365

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$5,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,4,($G$2:$G$5=A2)*$J$2:$J$5,1),$J$2:$J$5,0))
```

and

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$5,MATCH(B2,$H$2:$H$5,0))
```

The formulas above are in cells B2 and C2, as per the image below

[image]